# Usage of "be specified for"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I wrote:

> Each pattern **can be either specified** for data extraction or to restrict the occurrence of  nested patterns.
>
> If the pattern **is (was or has been ?) specified** for data extraction, we extract its content...

I used "be specified for something" to mean the purpose of each pattern, is it a correct usage of "specify"? What are other ways to say such sentences?

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah  to mean "the purpose of something", for example "this is specified for this work", "that is specified for that work"

Answer (score 2):

I think that the "*either*" in the first sentence is misplaced.  For better semantic flow of the sentence, put it after "*specified*":

> Each pattern can be specified *either* for data extraction *or* to restrict the occurrence of nested patterns.

Yes, you can use "specified" to indicate the purpose.

---

The sentence

> Something can be specified *either* for one thing *or* to do the other thing.

Can be alternatively written as

> Something ... designated **for** either one thing **or** *doing* the other thing.
>   Something ... **for** either *extracting* the data **or** *restricting* the occurrence of...

Perhaps the last one is better, but it's for you to decide.

Comment: Thank you, what about the second part of question?